# MAC can't access SharePoint

Tags: macos, dns, sharepoint-2013, intranet

I created an Intranet environment (SharePoint 2013) for my company and i can't connect MAC users to the intranet. My company use a domain but users can access the site without being in domain by using "NetBios over TCP/IP". For MAC users that option is not availble, so i find myself unable to connect them to the SharePoint environment. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, sharepoint can be made accessible over http(s): that should work as long as you do not require browsers to send their domain credentials with every access.
[Sending that is IMHO a real bad idea]

Since you said however: "NetBios over TCP/IP" is seems you're using filesharing.

Did you try:

Finder > Go > Connect to Server ... 
smb://server/path
Press Connect

The server: don't expect the netbios name to work, use DNS names.

That should prompt for credentials if they're needed.

Comment: Can you give an example of DNS entry for allowing MAC users to access SharePoint?